# How to change normal distribution from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distribution

I have a code not total like normal distribution. How can I change it from Mysql to SQL Server?

```
select latency
where  pow(e(), - pow((ln(latency) - 8.223) ,2)/2/0.3975) /sqrt(2*pi()) / 0.53  < 0.01
order by latency desc
```

Comment: 8.223 is AVG(Ln(latency)),  0.3975 is var(), 0.53 is stddev()

Comment: This isn't valid SQL, there's no `FROM` clause. What's the actual query you want to convert? Have you tried anything? What's the actual problem ?

Comment: I want to detect anomaly with normal distribution of some value. the code i found was in Mysql, but i use SQL Server. so i want to ask how can i change it?

Comment: I repeat this isn't valid SQL. This is the second question asking for a normal distribution in SQL Server today. Is this homework? That's the wrong question to begin with as a normal distribution isn't a value, it's a function. Have you tried googling for `t-sql normal distribution`? One of the very first results is [SQL Server T-SQL Code to Generate A Normal Distribution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4233/sql-server-tsql-code-to-generate-a-normal-distribution/).

Comment: Another possibility, one that examiners won't like but professionals would appreciate, is to actually use Python through [sp_execute_external_script](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9077/example-of-using-python-with-t-sql/). The Python distribution that comes with SQL Server 2017 and later includes NumPy, Pandas and scikit (among others) so you can easily write a script that uses `numpy.random.normal` or `scipy.stats.norm`.

Comment: I dont think you really understand my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the code, it works.

```sql
SELECT  latency
FROM    abc 
WHERE   exp( power((log(von) - 8.223) ,2)/2/0.3975) /sqrt(2*pi()) / 0.53  < 0.01
```